# Umbracco, forms and rich text editors

Tags: umbraco, richtext

Looking to understand if it is possible in Umbraco to have a form page, that contains a rich text CMS editor too?
Do I need a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco has a paid for plugin called Umbraco Forms (https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-forms/).

I'm sure there are likely plenty of free plugins for rich text editors if you want to create a custom form.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Bradley's answer, [Umbraco Forms package](https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-forms/) is what most Umbraco Developers would use.

It is not free, but if you are working for an Umbraco Gold Partner company, then it is currently free for your company. If this is your case, then you should be able to generate as many Umbraco Forms licences as you need for your Umbraco projects and use them without any issues, otherwise, you need to purchase it.

After installing [the Umbraco Forms package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoForms/) to your Umbraco project, you can create your Forms directly from the Umbraco Backoffice>Forms session:

[image]

You use "Answer types" to create your form fields. There is not a Rich Text Editor answer type out of the box at the moment.

[image]

Your options could be;

- Using a [Short](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/umbracoforms/editor/creating-a-form/fieldtypes/#short-answer) or [Long Answer](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/umbracoforms/editor/creating-a-form/fieldtypes/#long-answer) answer type.
- Using the [Title and Description](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/umbracoforms/editor/creating-a-form/fieldtypes/#title-and-description) answer type.
- Alternatively, you can extend the Umbraco backoffice for Umbraco forms and create your custom answer types by creating your custom Field types as [described here](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/umbracoforms/developer/extending/adding-a-fieldtype) . While doing this, you might need some custom workflows, and [here is how you can create custom workflows](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/umbracoforms/developer/extending/adding-a-workflowtype).